# Using Teamcity to deploy css into git repository

Tags: git, tfs, teamcity

I have a git repository set up for our angular project. The styling for the website is being worked on by a separate front end team who will be checking in their work to a TFVC repository in TFS. We are using Teamcity for CI.

I would like to be able to deploy the latest style sheets from the TFVC repository on checkin to the project on git so it is always up to date when we do a pull.

Can Teamcity do this or is there a way to do it in git?

Comment: I guess you have to setup a hook on your TFS VC repository (I have never used such a thing) to push the changes to git automatically

Comment: Thanks. After thinking about it, I'm just going to import the css as a bower package from the front end teams repo. Turns out that's pretty straight forward.

Comment: You can set up a link to the TFS VC using TeamCity and then have a commit trigger in just the same way as you would in Git.

Comment: Are you using Git in TFS?

Comment: Yeah, I'll take a look at TFS-Git if we fail to talk the front end team in to using git. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TFS-Git or git-tf to push back and forth between a TFVC repository and Git.

As this is just an executable you should be able to do it in Team City or anywhere.